# "padrino rake sq:migrate -e development"doesn't update collection

Tags: ruby, migration, rake, sequel, padrino

I would like to add one more field to accounts table.
So I have done this

```
1) padrino g migration AddPhoneNumberToAccounts phone_number:string
This make a migration file named 
038_add_phone_number_to_accounts.rb
2) and I migrated.
padrino rake db:migrate -e development
But it make errors
/Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/extensions/migration.rb:601:in `block in get_migration_files': Missing migration version: 6 (Sequel::Migrator::Error)
        from /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/extensions/migration.rb:601:in `upto'
        from /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/extensions/migration.rb:601:in `get_migration_files'
....
```

How to solve this? sometimes I didn't get this errors but it doesn't update table either.
Thanks.

Comment: What about file number 006_*? Is this one missing?

Comment: Thanks, it was because 006_* migration files was not there.

Comment: great. You should mark it as solved though. Thanks